# Button down/up in objective c for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a button, and I'd like to call a function when the user pushes it then call a different function when he releases it.

Right now I'm using this to create the button:

```
[ScanButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scanButtonPressed) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to call scanButtonPressed. As of now scanButtonPressed is only called upon release. How do I change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about by trying a control event [other than `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW65)?

Answer (score 1):

Try - `UIControlEventTouchDown` .

Answer (score 0):

This contains all of the different events you can pass to a button
[UIControl Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Try looking at these; both UIControlEventTouchUpInside and UIControlEventTouchDown will work.